# how to change admin password of FXOS version 2100 and 4100 series

Tags: cisco-firepower

When I try to set new password of user admin,
it said admin cannot reset self password:

```
firepower-fxos# scope security

firepower-fxos /security # show local-user
User Name       First Name      Last name
--------------- --------------- ---------
admin

firepower-fxos /security # enter local-user admin

firepower-fxos /security/local-user # set password

Enter a password:

Confirm the password:

**Software Error: Admin user admin cannot reset self password**
```

How to set the new password of admin user?

Comment: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/firepower-2100-series/213247-configure-or-change-fxos-firepower-2100.html

Answer (score 2):

Worth trying :

Create a new local user, grant him admin privileges.

Then login with this user and reset the password of the `admin` user.

This method has the benefit of preventing you to lock you out of the device in case of issue with the new password.

Comment: That is how I have done it. A second account to change the admin password. You should have more than one account anyway and should use it regularly. The admin account should not the be primary user for management use.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have tried what you suggest and it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
FXOS# scope security 
FXOS/security # set password
Enter old password:
Enter new password:
Confirm new password:
```